# How can I use this here with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<style>
    .disNone{display:none;}
    .disBlock{display:block;}
</style>

<script>
    $(".visitlink.item span").click(function(){
        $(".summary.item").toggleClass("disNone");
        $(".fullsum.item").toggleClass("disBlock");  
    });
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="coursebox">
        <div class="summary item">summary</div>
        <div class="fullsum item">fullsum</div>
        <div class="visitlink item"><span>Readmore</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="coursebox">
        <div class="summary item">summary</div>
        <div class="fullsum item">fullsum</div>
        <div class="visitlink item"><span>Readmore</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I apply class on click `div` it is working on both `div` how can I write the code to target this.

Comment: please write jquery end of html and check

Comment: how can i target click div it is working but working on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change to

```
 $(this).parent().siblings(".summary.item").toggleClass("disNone");
 $(this).parent().siblings(".fullSum.item").toggleClass("disBlock");
```

As the clicked element is span element and the target elements are the siblings of it's parent div.

Comment: OP is targeting on `span`. So can we use`siblings()`?. There are no `sibilings()`. I think you need to add `parent()`

Comment: @RinoRaj I'm currently mobile so it takes a bit time in typing. Updated though and thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @RinoRaj I'm currently mobile so it takes a bit time in typing. Updated though and thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo**

```js
$(".visitlink.item span").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".coursebox").find(".summary.item").toggleClass("disNone");
  $(this).closest(".coursebox").find(".fullsum.item").toggleClass("disBlock");
  
});
```

```css
.disNone {
  display: none;
}
.disBlock {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="coursebox">
    <div class="summary item">summary</div>
    <div class="fullsum item">fullsum</div>

    <div class="visitlink item"><span>Readmore</span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="coursebox">
    <div class="summary item">summary</div>
    <div class="fullsum item">fullsum</div>

    <div class="visitlink item"><span>Readmore</span>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Instead of two parent chaining use closest. Which traverse faster than parent.

Comment: @Jai I tried using closest. It was not working. I tried something like `$(this).parent().closest().find(".fullsum.item").toggleClass("disBlock");`